# iterate through list like in sliding window

Tags: python

How can I implement this kind of iteration similar to sliding window method in python.

```
Given s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 3]
   [2, 3, 4]
      [3, 4, 5]    
         [4, 5, 6]
            [5, 6]
               [6]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]    
for i in range(len(l)):
    print l[i : i+3]
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6]
[6]
```